# Store protocol buffers message in a document database

Tags: c#, mongodb, protocol-buffers, grpc

We are using protocol buffers messages over grpc to implement a micro service architecture between several components developed in several languages (c# - c++ - java).

One of our component has the responsibility to persist those messages in a document store. Currently we are using mongodb with the c# driver and protocol buffers c# generated classes required hand written serialization/deserialization code to work with c# driver).

Is there any document store / database that could store directly protocol buffers message (not as binary blob) and enable query on those messages properties ?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write a "redis module" (4.0) to do the job, similar to how [rejson is implemented](http://redismodules.com/modules/rejson/); redis modules allow you to put your own code 100% inside the server. You'd need to think about how schemas should work, though, and what operations you want to support against the data; essentially: can you leave it raw in a single binary string, or will you need to extract the data inside the server, just using the raw API on the boundary?

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at redis module concept.
I guess the server would need to extract the data in order to allow indexing of some of the message properties, and query or sort on others.

Comment: @FIF that would be a design choice for you, and would depend on what you need to do with the data, and how big the values *are*, etc etc; nothing here is inbuilt